Ruby on Rails App crashing After deployment to Heroku
I am working on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Hartl. I am on the first app for "Hello World". It is working fine in my Cloud9 environment, but when I try to deploy to Heroku it crashes. Looking at the logs, nothing is jumping out at me as the issue. Below are the logs from Heroku after the deploy and it tries to start.
I have marked the lines that seem relevant to me with an asterisk at the beginning, but I am just starting with Ruby and Rails so they may not be important. I see a couple references to SQLite3, but SQLite3 is not in my Gemfile and the application is not even using a database connection. It is just a static page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
2024-11-14T15:05:07.414803+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-11-14T15:05:09.549081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2024-11-14T15:05:11.223250+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2024-11-14T15:05:11.223266+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4 application starting in production
2024-11-14T15:05:11.223267+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659268+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
* 2024-11-14T15:05:11.659304+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.25/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659308+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659309+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659309+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659313+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659319+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:268:in `resolve_pool_config'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659319+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659319+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:52:in `establish_connection'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659319+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `class_eval'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `block in execute_hook'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:85:in `with_execution_control'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:90:in `execute_hook'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659323+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:76:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659324+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659324+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `run_load_hooks'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659324+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:333:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659324+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659325+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659326+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659326+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:26:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `const_get'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659330+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `get'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659330+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:173:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659330+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:47:in `block in ls'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659330+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659330+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659331+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:168:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659331+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659331+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659331+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659332+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659332+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659332+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:413:in `block in eager_load_all'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659332+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:411:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659332+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:411:in `eager_load_all'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659333+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659333+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659334+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659334+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659335+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659336+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659346+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659346+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659351+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659352+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659352+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659353+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659353+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659353+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659353+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659353+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659354+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659355+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659356+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659358+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659359+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659360+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659361+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659362+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659369+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659369+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659369+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659369+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659370+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659371+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659371+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor.rb:538:in `dispatch'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659380+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659380+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659380+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659380+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659380+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659382+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
* 2024-11-14T15:05:11.659393+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.25/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659394+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659394+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659394+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659397+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659398+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:268:in `resolve_pool_config'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659398+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659398+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:52:in `establish_connection'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659398+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659399+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `class_eval'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659399+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `block in execute_hook'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659408+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:85:in `with_execution_control'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659408+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:90:in `execute_hook'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659408+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:76:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659408+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659409+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `run_load_hooks'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659409+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:333:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659410+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659410+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659411+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659419+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659419+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659419+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659419+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659419+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:26:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659420+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `const_get'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659421+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `get'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659422+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:173:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659424+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:47:in `block in ls'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659425+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659425+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659426+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:168:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659427+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659428+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659429+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659430+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659432+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659433+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:413:in `block in eager_load_all'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659434+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:411:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659436+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.18/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:411:in `eager_load_all'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659437+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659438+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659439+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659447+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659447+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659448+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659448+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659448+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659448+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659449+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659449+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659450+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659451+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659452+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659460+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659460+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659460+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659460+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659460+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659460+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659461+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659470+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659470+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659470+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659471+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.10/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659471+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659480+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659480+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659480+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659481+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659481+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor.rb:538:in `dispatch'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659483+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659483+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-11-14T15:05:11.659485+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
* 2024-11-14T15:05:11.704420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
* 2024-11-14T15:05:11.729518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

I have tried redeploying several times and restarting the Heroku Dyno, but it keeps doing the same thing. I even created a new app on Heroku and redeployed to it, but same errors.

When I went in to pull the new stack trace I realized it was still trying to reference SQLite3. Looking at the database.yml file and noticed it was still trying to load some SQLite3 items through the "Default". I took out the default reference under production and put in info for PostgreSQL instead. That fixed the issue. The build completes successfully now and the application loads. As a note, the app I was trying to do was static pages only with no backend database.
Thanks everyone for your help and guidance.

During loading of your database configuration, Rails tries to load the sqlite3 gem and fails.
Thus, it appears that you have configured a database with the sqlite3 adapter. To fix this, you should edit your database.yml file to use the correct database for the production environment, likely the Heroku hosted database of your dyno.

Thanks. That did get rid of the errors on load involving the SQLite3 errors, but the app is still crashing when it tries to load and I get an Application Error screen when visiting the site. The same error at the bottom of the logs I posted. Where it says "Process exited with status 1" and "State changed from starting to crashed"

Could you please provide an updated stack trace.
